# Making a full-screen animation on Android? Should I use OPENGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Say I need to make several full-screen animation that would consist of about 500 frames each.
Animation should be playing at a reasonable speed - supposedly not less, then 20fps - and pictures should be of a reasonable quality, not overly compressed.

What method do you think should I use?

So far I tried:

```
1. storing each frame as a compressed JPEG
2. before animation starts, loading each frame into a byteArray
3. as the animation plays, decode corresponding byteArray into a bitmap
and draw it on a surface view.
```

Problem - speed is too low, usually about 5-10 FPS.

I have thought of two other options.

1. turning all animations into one movie file... but I guess there might be problems with starting, pausing and seeking to the exactly right frame... what do you think?
2. another option I thought about was using OPENGL ( while I never worked with it before ), to play animation frame by frame. What do you think, would opengl be able to handle it?

Thanks!

---

edit, i managed to peek into talkingtom, and found that it contains about 20megs of well compressed JPEGs, like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle it in a couple of different ways.

1. It sounds like decoding is your bottleneck. You could try making all the 3 steps including the decoding before playing the animation, so you will just have to draw the already-converted bitmaps.
2. OpenGL is definitely up to the task in the sense that it will probably never be your bottleneck. But as said above, the drawing does not seem to be the problem.
3. Animating on the device. In case you are animating geometric objects or pixmaps and the animation has a common background you could reuse, separate the animation into "actors" and move them around - this will require much less data.

EDIT : Complex animations on mobile devices are rarely full-screen movies or series of images - the amount of (redundant) data would be overwhelming (as you have noticed already). They are animated 2D and 3D models. For 3D it is advisable to use OpenGL, for 2D, common canvas drawing may be enough. To make it even more efficient, you could split the model into separate parts and animate them separately (would look similar to SouthPark animations). You can combine this with using spritesheets (like separate small movie strips) to animate separate parts. This would give you much more flexibility while still using less data than a compressed movie.

Comment: 1. how many full-screen bitmaps can an android device hold in its memory? Usually about 5 ;)

Comment: @RogerTravis - depends on the resoltion and bit depth, but probably not enough. I personally would use the third approach.

Comment: since in my case the animation is taking up almost all screen, the third approach won't work...

Comment: @RogerTravis - As long as the animation is not fully consisting of photographic images, I would still prefer the third option over fullscreen images, or a movie for reasons of data size. I may be misunderstanding your requirements though. do you happen to have an example of such an animation?

Comment: An example would be the talking tom app ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outfit7.talkingtom2free ), where the cat is almost full screen.

Comment: edited the post, it appears that TalkingTom consists of series of JPEGs, which I believe is the right way to go is such case. There's no use of cutting the animation into sprites, if they would still take about 80% of the screen. So the only question is how to make this jpegs play with a good FPS rate. )

Answer (score 2):

I really think you need to turn it into a movie file - that will give you some appropriate compression and android can do all the work with the media player. I believe getting to the right frame is fairly easy but you may have to use lower compression on the video stream to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [universal tween engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/) can fix your performance problem.

Comment: It looks like this engine is mostly for animating some small sprites flying down some path, GUIs, etc. , rather then playing a true full screen frame by frame animation... or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: In the example application  it has a fullscreen splash screen animation and runs quite well. As i told before i "may" do the trick. you better give it a shot. kostja's 3rd aproach is logical too.